# TF31002 Can't connect to TFS online from VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

### Problem

I'm using `VisualStudio 2012 Ultimate v11.0.50727.1 Update 4` and `VisualStudio 2013 Ultimate v12.0.21005 EL` and I'm able to connect to TFS through any browser. But suddenly I can't connect to TFS at ***xxxxx*.VisualStudio.com** from within VisualStudio anymore. Yesterday I easily did a Check-In at work with the same account. but I can't connect to TFS at home.

This is the URL I'm using: (I've tried changing it a bit like adding /tfs or /DefaultCollection)

[image]

I'm stuck with this, I've tried different ways but none have worked so far and it's still giving me these errors: TF31002, TF300324 and TF205020

[image]

**TF31002** (this error happens when trying to Add a new server)

**TF205020**: Could not connect to server ‘https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection’. This server was used in your last session, but it might be offline or unreachable. Confirm that the server is available on the network. To attempt to connect again, or to a different server, click ‘Connect To Team Foundation Server’ in Team Explorer or the Team menu.

**TF400324**: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection.
Technical information (for administrator):
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

(The last 2 errors happen when VisualStudio is trying to login to tfs)

### I've tried these:

1. Go to VisualStudio.com and Sign out from all browsers
2. Delete Cookies and Caches of IE10 (and test when IE has signed in to visualstudio.com or signed out of it)
3. Go to Regedit and set the DWORD to 0 in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\Instances`
4. [Browse](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613214/TF400324-Team-Foundation-services-are-not-availabl) to `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache` and delete everything
5. Delete all credentials from Windows Credential Manager (and remove Link Online ID)
6. Installed VS2013
7. Installed Team Explorer 2013
8. Installed VS2012 Update 4
9. Installed a fresh copy of Windows 8

### What I want.

After some long and desperate time of trying to connect to TFS online, **Now I'm just looking for a way to Check-in my changes.** (doing it by hand is not an option because there's a large number of changes and I can't even know which files are changed since last check-in)

Comment: Proxyserver? Firewall?

Comment: Try enabling TFS Client tracing to see if there is a more descriptive error in there: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2007/03/30/tfs-client-tracing.aspx

Comment: Can you connect from another machine?

Comment: No proxy and no firewall, and the client tracing didn't work

Comment: Yes other computers are working, so was mine until yesterday! any other idea?

Comment: How did client tracing not work? What can you see in the log files that client tracing produces?

Comment: It didn't create any log files, (I changed its directory to d: as well)

Comment: You're using Vsiaul Studio 2012 it seems, did you update the Version=10.0.0... to read 11.0....

Comment: Ok, It asked for credentials and after sign in it gave me TF31002. this is the simplified log file: http://txt.do/1srj

Comment: Do you have any antivirus blocking your tfs connection?

Comment: In win7 I have Windows essentials (as before), in win8 I have no antivirus.

Comment: Did you tried Cross-platform Command-line Client for Team Foundation Server to check in your files? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785

Comment: When I try to login it says: An error occurred: Access denied connecting to TFS server https://xxxx.visualstudio.com/ (authenticating as xxxx@gmail.com)

Comment: Have you changed your account's password in those days?

Comment: No I haven't although I recently added an alternative credential to my account in visualStudio.com but it didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried contacting [Visual Studio Online support](http://www.visualstudio.com/support/support-overview-vs)?

Comment: I found a similar question to what I was about to ask, and the answer was It's fixed! So I didn't ask.

Comment: The list you tried fixed my issue... Might be worth others trying if they get the same issue! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a way to check-in all changes of the home computer at work computer.

1. Copy the local TFS folder from home computer (including the hidden `$tf` subfolder) to work computer.
2. Install [Team Foundation Sidekicks for 2012](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm)
3. Search for the home computer name
4. Click on `Update Workspace Computer Name`

   [image]
5. Go to `Source Control Explorer` and open `Workspaces...`

   [image]
6. Check `Show remote workspaces` checkbox (if the home workspace is not shown)
7. Edit the home workspace
8. Remove current mapping
9. Map `$/` to the local folder (which has `$tf`)
10. When click on `Advanced` It should look like this:

    [image]
11. Switch to the new Workspace and done!

It seems to me that private workspace is what causing the problem, and I will try to change it to public after I checked in.

---

### Edit

I've found another workaround which requires no workspace hacks. (This method is originally designed for recovering from wrong check-ins)

1. In Source Control Explorer select root (collection, not project)
2. click `Compare folders`
3. in `source version` section choose the latest safe version
4. in `target path` section browse to the not-checked-in folder
5. make sure both paths end with same name (e.g. $/MyProj and E:\FromHome\TFS\MyProj)
6. (set any additional settings...) and click OK
7. DoubleClick on files with different value of `Yes` and write down the names of those file that should be loaded from local folder (right part of screen probably shows local)
8. Open those files from Solution Explorer and overwrite them with local files

Answer (score 5):

I just saw this link and it totally worked for me after nothing else would: http://www.cnblogs.com/CuteNet/p/3556276.html

regedit:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio 2013
2. Delete this folder in the registry (just “TokenStorage” – nothing else):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue where I couldn't connect (TF31002) to TFS 2010 using VS 2010, 2012 and 2013 on my laptop but can connect from web and other servers just fine. 
I tried almost all suggestions given by various sources online but had no luck.

I was getting ready to reimage tha laptop but as one last try I started comparing config's between another virtual machine (where the connection was successful) to my laptop. I found that in my laptop I have additional defaultProxy settings in 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config’

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX" usesystemdefault="false"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

After deleting the above node completely I was able to connect to TFS 2010 successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solved the problem for me! Thanks! This problem also solved the problem that I couldn't connect to Visual Studio Gallery and Nuget with the  Nuget Package Manager.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue few days back 
1. Disable your firewall(not recommended)
2. Run VS 2013 in admin mode.
3. Disable antivirus or add TFS in whitelist.
4. Select connect to TFS and create a new project in another directory (Local copy)
5. Check the directory for access(**Read only by default change the permissions**)
6. try to check in now.

After changing the permissions to the local directory i was able to check in my changes.

Comment: I remembered a problem with Windows Essentials. I will try that at home. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and for me the problem was Anti-Virus software (Kaspersky Endpoint Security 8).  See this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2014/07/24/can-t-connect-to-visual-studio-online-from-any-version-of-in-vs-quot-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send-quot.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL first!

I had a problem with such URL:

https://domain-name.com

Turns out that symbol "-" where replaced with some special char `&shy;`. But Visual Studio 2012(2013) did not indicate that anyhow. Apparently it was not able to find such domain. As result same issue TF31002 and a day spent in research.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with Visual Studio Premium 2013 connecting to our project from inside VS. It kept returning TF31002, but I could access it with a browser.

From the browser I went to Home->Activities->Open New instance of Visual Studio and my tfs project loaded right into the Team Explorer frame.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I wanted to connect to the TFS with Visual Studio. This solved my problem:

- I used a VPN connection to the server
- I used the ip address instead of the link given by the TFS (http://"ip address":8080/tfs instead of http://"link":8080/tfs)